# Pre(-)processing/post(-)processing hyphen presence in research publications written in UK/US English

Tags: programming

Which of the following spellings of pre|post(-)processing are the most commonly used in research publications written in UK English and in US English?

`pre-processing, post-processing` versus `preprocessing, postprocessing`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both the hyphenated and non-hyphenated versions are acceptable in both British and American English. A quick NGrams query shows that the spelling "preprocessing" is prevalent over "pre-proceesing" on both sides of the Ocean. However, in British English, "post-processing" has been spelled slightly more often with a hyphen than without.

References:

- [BrE, pre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preprocessing%2Cpre-processing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreprocessing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpre%20-%20processing%3B%2Cc0)
- [BrE, post](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postprocessing%2Cpost-processing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostprocessing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpost%20-%20processing%3B%2Cc0)
- [AmE, pre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preprocessing%2Cpre-processing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreprocessing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpre%20-%20processing%3B%2Cc0)
- [AmE, post](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postprocessing%2Cpost-processing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostprocessing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpost%20-%20processing%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary is the spelling authority providing current spelling for research purposes.  The Oxford English Dictionary provides:

[preprocessing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/preprocess) (no hyphen)

[post-processing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/post-processing) (with a hyphen)

I understand your inclination to either use no hyphen in either one or use a hyphen in both of them, but the Oxford English Dictionary does not bend to your pet peeves or minor bouts of obsessive-compulsiveness.  If you wish to conform to the established spelling, you will write them as they appear above, one without a hyphen and the other with.

By the way, this is not the only instance of this.  If when referring to someone's age you describe them as being "mid-twenties," there is a hyphen.  If you describe them as being "late twenties," there is no hyphen.  If you describe them as being "mid- to late twenties," you clearly put a hyphen after one and no hyphen after the other.  You don't add a hyphen between "late" and "twenties" or delete the hyphen after "mid" to satisfy some personal need to have it all match.

Comment: Note that in editing, consistency often trumps spelling. For instance, if a primarily referenced dictionary shows a closed-form version of four related words that are used in a piece of text but a fifth word uses a hyphenated form, then it's commonly acceptable to spell the fifth word in closed form—regardless of its actual spelling. Otherwise, the exception is jarring and takes the reader out of the text. (An editor making such an exception would note it in their style sheet.)  But if you are considering each word in isolation, then yes. Barring some other reasoning, go with the dictionary.

Comment: While a little snarky, this reply is definitely the better one with good argumentation and examples. Thanks!